# Firebase Reset Password Swift

Tags: ios, swift, passwords, firebase, reset

I was wondering if you guys could show me how to setup Reset Password in Swift, I am currently using Firebase as my backend service. I just need the code.

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/password.html#section-reset-email

Comment: If you're having a specific problem: show what you've already tried. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 83):

The answer is in the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#/c:objc(cs)FIRAuth(im)sendPasswordResetWithEmail:completion:):

> `-sendPasswordResetWithEmail:completion:`
>
> Initiates a password reset for the given email address.
>
> See [FIRAuthErrors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes.html#/c:objc(cs)FIRAuthErrors) for a list of error codes that are common to all API methods.

In Swift 3.x and Firebase 3.x it will look like this:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordReset(withEmail: "email@email") { error in
    // Your code here
}
```

Edit:

Firebase 4 changed the Firebase functions to be more aligned with the naming conventions in Swift.

```
Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: "email@email") { error in
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: If my answer was correct, please accept it!  :-)

Comment: Thanks @Jay +1 for you

Comment: Here dear @Jay, your +1. Use it wisely

Comment: @Jay people like you make the internet a better place.. and googling a lot easier! I appreciate it! +1

Comment: What do you do once the password reset email has been sent? Does the link in the email take the user back to the app?

Comment: @Jay How to send new `password.text`?

Comment: @BhanukaIsuru I don't understand the question. What does password.text mean?

Comment: new password.. user needs to type new password..right?

Comment: @Jay sorry, I am very beginning to ios. I thought user need to type new password..

Comment: @BhanukaIsuru the password reset sends you a link that allows you to reset the password. You don't need any other code.

Comment: This function also cab be use for reset password: Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to:self.parentNewPassword,completion:{(error) in 
   // code here
 })