# Firebase not sending sendPasswordReset email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, passwords

I've been trying to get Firebase to send a Password Reset Email with the following code:

```
let email = "myemailaddress@gmail.com"

@IBAction func changePasswordTapped(_ sender: Any) {
                    
       Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: self.email) { (error) in
           print(self.email)
       }
    }
```

The console prints out my email address as per the `print(self.email)`, but I haven't received any emails after multiple attempts and waiting more than a day. I've checked all of my email folders, including spam.

Is there something else that needs to be implemented for this to work?

I really appreciate any help/guidance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Reset Password Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808352/firebase-reset-password-swift)

Comment: Well, your not checking to see if there's an error so the code will just silently fail and you won't know why. You should add error handling within the closure like `if let err == error {  print(err.localizedDescription) }` and see if it prints and error. Then' you'll know what the issue was.

Comment: Thank you @Jay! That helped me dig deeper. Hard-coding the email address didn't work as a test because Firebase couldn't associate it with the user. So just setting the email as `let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase did not allow for me to hard-code the email address. I was getting this error:

```
There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
```

Once I set the email address to the currentUser, it worked:

```
let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email

@IBAction func changePasswordTapped(_ sender: Any) {
                    
       Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: self.email) { (error) in
           print(self.email)
       }
    }
```